# How do I center these images in the middle (HTML and CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I would like for these four images to be centered in the middle of my screen while still remaining side by side as they already are.

```html
<h2><img src="images/Colorado Parks.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Parks webpage" id="colParks"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Colorado Monuments.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Monuments webpage" usemap="#goToColMons" id="colMonuments"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Spotlight Park.gif" alt="Button to Spotlight Park webpage" id="spotPark"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Places to Stay.gif" alt="Button to places to Stay webpage" id="toStay"/></h2>
```

```css
#colMonuments, #spotPark, #toStay, #colParks {
    float:left;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind you don't want to use blank spaces in file names. Best to go with a dash. Colorado-Parks.gif Google "blank space in url" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `display:inline-block` is the best for that.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nn82mzjj/

```
.class-name {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.class-name h2 {
    margin: 0 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; /*adjustable*/
}
```

Comment: What do I replace .class-name with?

Comment: @ClaudioPietrantonio I just made a quick demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/nn82mzjj/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qqyukf6L/)

First of all we add container to all our images (in our example is div with id images-container), after that we set this container to be placed in the center of the page.
 Within this container we  set our `h2` elements as `inline-block` elements , after that we can set in containing element (in our example is div with id images-container) `text-align:center` to center `h2` with images.

HTML:

```
<div id="images-container">

<h2><img src="images/Colorado Parks.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Parks webpage" id="colParks"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Colorado Monuments.gif" alt="Button to Colorado Monuments webpage" usemap="#goToColMons" id="colMonuments"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Spotlight Park.gif" alt="Button to Spotlight Park webpage" id="spotPark"/></h2>
<h2><img src="images/Places to Stay.gif" alt="Button to places to Stay webpage" id="toStay"/></h2>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#colMonuments, #spotPark, #toStay, #colParks {
float:left;
margin: 8px;
}


#images-container {
margin: 20% auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
display: inline-block;
}

h2:after {
content: "";
display: block;
clear: both;
}
```